# Class in Python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create a class about birds with a few different methods. This is just theoretical code. Is there anything that is inherently wrong with the code from a syntactical or semantics point of view?  If so, please fix.

```
class Bird(object):
    def __init__(self, Height, Weight, HasFeathers, CapableofFlying, BirdMigrates, BirdSings, BirdEatsworms):
        self.Height=Height
        self.Weight=Weight
        self.HasFeathers=HasFeathers
        self.HasFeathers= HasFeathers
        self.CapableofFlying= getCapableofFlying
        self.BirdMigrates=BirdMigrates
        self.BirdSings=BirdSings
        self.BirdEatsworms=BirdEatsworms

def Height():
    return Height

def Weight():
    return Weight

def HasFeathers():
    if  getHasFeathers == "No":
        return “The bird does not have feathers”
    else:
        return “The bird has feathers”

def CapableofFlying():
    if CapableofFlying== "No":
        return “The bird is incapable of flying”
    else:
        return “The bird  is capable of flying”

def BirdMigrates():
    if BirdMigrates= "No":
        return “The bird does not migrate”
    else:
        return “The bird migrates”

def BirdSings():
    if BirdSings= "No":
        return “The bird cannot sing”
    else:
        return “The bird  can sing”

def BirdEatsworms():
    if BirdEatsworms= "No":
        return “The bird does not eat worms”
    else:
        return “The bird  eats worms”
```

Comment: Every line that ends in an ":", the next line (and all lines you want in that block) should be indented one level in from the line with the ":"

Comment: Well the indentation is all wrong, for one, and then many other things. Maybe you should see what Python says first?

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell since the indentation is way off.  Any chance you could fix that?

Comment: there are several syntax errors... for example it is not `if x=0:` but it is `if x==0`, and please cure the indentation as it is impossible to know if you wanted those function inside or outside the class (In both cases I see errors).

Comment: In `__init__`, are you defining class methods to be the functions you've written outside of the class? Please fix the indentation.

Comment: On top of the other problems, all of the functions or methods make no sense. (And if they're methods, they need to take a `self` parameter.) For example, inside the `Weight` function, you do `return Weight`. For example, inside `CapableOfFlying`, you (try to) check to see if `CapableOfFlying` is `False`. Since `CapableOfFlying` is a function—the very function you're in the middle of—it's obviously not `False`.

Comment: To answer your specific question: just about _everything_ is wrong from a semantical point of view except that `__init__` seems like it's trying to do something reasonable, and so much is wrong from a syntactic point of view that it's often hard to even figure out what it's even trying to do, and that doesn't even get into the stylistic issues that make it impossible to guess your intentions (which is critical when those intentions aren't obvious from the syntax).

Comment: @user3034084 Not completely, the class definition still has many indentation errors...  I just fixed those too, and the spelling mistake in the title.

Comment: @SethMMorton - Why do classes not require any details to give information back.

Comment: @user3034084 I'm sorry... I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @SethMMorton- If I was to call a method and then not give any input, why would it give me an output?

Comment: I see.  You have actually written most of this class incorrectly.  I corrected the egregious errors, but not the ones related to the question itself.  Let me make an answer that will hopefully answer this last question.  (If you had included this last question in the original question, it is likely you would have gotten an answer sooner.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Bird(object):
    def __init__(self, height, weight, has_feathers, capable_of_flying, bird_migrates, bird_sings, bird_eats_worms):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.has_feathers = has_feathers
        self.capable_of_flying = capable_of_flying
        self.bird_migrates = bird_migrates
        self.bird_sings = bird_sings
        self.bird_eats_worms = bird_eats_worms

    def get_height(self):
        return self.height

    def get_weight(self):
        return self.weight

    def get_has_feathers(self):
        if self.has_feathers:
            return "The bird has feathers"
        else:
            return "The bird does not have feathers"

    # Etc...
```

A few things of note:

- You cannot have a function and variable of the same name, so I had to rename the functions to "get_..."
- If you want to make a function part of a class (called a method) then it has to be indented to be in the class.
- A class method needs to have the class object passed to it as the first parameter (called `self` by convention).  This is how the class knows information about itself.
- The variables in the class need to be accessed with `classvar.variable`, where inside the class `classvar` is `self`.
- CamelCase should only be used for class names in python.  Use all_lower_case_and_underscore for variable and function names.

You would use the class like this:

```
penguin = Bird(10, 30, True, False, False, True, False)
print penguin.get_has_feathers() # "The bird has feathers"
```

---

The whole "get_..." paradigm is an "anti-pattern" in python (you might have a C++ background where this is considered the correct way to do it).  It's better to just expose the variables directly:

```
class Bird(object):
    def __init__(self, height, weight, has_feathers, capable_of_flying, bird_migrates, bird_sings, bird_eats_worms):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        if has_feathers:
            self.has_feathers = "The bird has feathers"
        else:
            self.has_feathers = "The bird does not have feathers"
        # etc...

penguin = Bird(10, 30, True, False, False, True, False)
print penguin.has_feathers # "The bird has feathers"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `pip install pylint`
2. `pylint <my_file_that_contains_Bird_class.py>`

Try this, and it will show you pretty much everything you need to format your code.

If you want to go little more deeper, do `pip install pep8` and run `pep8 <my_file>.py`